# Downvotes should be cleared on move

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, down-votes, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset post score to 0 on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration)

In my experience, most moved items wind up with a few downvotes before they're moved, almost always due to it having been posted in the wrong place. These downvotes persist in the new location.

Shouldn't a question start fresh with its votes if it's moved to another Trilogy site?

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration which is currently at `[status-planned]`

Comment: Indeed it is, cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps. It would at least give the question more of a fair chance now that it has been migrated to its (presumed) correct home.

One related side-effect of question migration is that the votes (and comments?) on a post cannot be removed or changed on the new site, even if the user who left those votes/comments has their accounts linked on the new site (a corollary of this is the observed effect that a second vote can be left).

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, I agree. But perhaps the risk of downvotes also provides an incentive to the poster to post the question in the appropriate site in the first place. Otherwise, a section of people might never bother. This just a thought, I really don't have any proof that this will be the case.

Comment: I'd venture a guess that 99%+ of moved items come from users who are unfamiliar with the site, let alone the tendency to get downvoted for posting in the wrong site.

Comment: True. But my point is that this helps in keeping any user who is aware/concerned about downvotes (i.e. all non-newbies) away from this practice.

Comment: I doubt that non-newbies need to be "kept away from the practice".