# Reopening a question after a long time: is the reputation still restored?

Tags: support, migration, reopen-closed

An off topic question appeared on the Linguistics site. The right proposal is still in the "follow it" phase so I can't migrate it yet.

I was closing it, but I thought that the off topic close reason brings a -2 to the OP. Considering the question was not bad per se, but just off topic, I (temporarily) reopened it.

The reputation got restored, so my question is:

If I close the question now and reopen it when I can migrate it to its right proposal, will he recover the reputation regardless of the amount of time the question stayed closed?

Comment: `the Off topic close reason brings a -2 to the OP` Is that a real thing? Does it happen all across the network? Or only betas?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox - as far as I know it's network wide.

Comment: Yes, me too, I think I saw it happening on English Language & Usage too.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox [This request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati) is marked as [status-complete], so I think it *is* network wide as ChrisF said.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Thanks for posting that. :)

Comment: Alenanno and @Zaphod - you can see all the changes [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) in nice neat list. As for the question, note that it says *Off Topic (**excluding questions that get migrated elsewhere**)* :)

Comment: Thanks @ShaDowWizArd (and everyone else). Changelog bookmarked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I close the question now and reopen it when I can migrate it to its right proposal, will he recover the reputation regardless of the amount of time the question stayed closed?

The *auto* downvote that happens when you close a question as [off-topic gets cleared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati), the ones put in by the users remains as it is. That said, [migration clears the downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration) on the question & the question gets deleted, so yes ultimately the OP regains the reputation back.

Comment: Thank you! I'll close it for now and migrate it later. :)