# Reset question score partly upon re-opening and staying open

Tags: feature-request, score, reopened-questions

I mostly write from a perspective of stackoverflow.com but the idea is general.

Question that get closed typically also accrue downvotes, the score is mostly negative. A small part of these questions gets improved and re-opened later on. If they get re-opened they might get closed again and sometimes there are several cycles of this, but in general, if a question is re-opened and remains so, it's on-topic. But the score of the question is likely yet quite negative. The chances of the question to be seen and answered are substantially lower than if the asker would just have asked a new question instead. Some close notifications even seem to encourage asking new questions instead of improving the closed question.

[image]

There seems to be an incentive to ask new questions instead of improving closed questions. To bring a re-opened question on par with new questions, one would be tempted to reset the question score upon re-opening.

On the other hand, re-opened questions were closed once and caused curation effort. One could see the often negative score as kind of penalty for causing the curation effort. On the other, other hand, one could argue that re-opened and remaining open questions are of higher quality than completely new questions because they are more likely on-topic.

As a compromise and with the aim to encourage people to improve closed questions and to avoid people asking new questions instead of waiting for their closed questions to get reopened, I suggest that the score is capped to -2 after re-opening and remaining open for say 24 hours, to allow a somewhat fresh start.

That would mean undoing some downvotes in some cases, so a difficulty is how to choose which ones. Maybe that could be done randomly.

My search for similar requests only found [Reset post score to 0 on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration), which specifically deals with migrated questions. Migrated questions have the score capped to 0 it seems.

Comment: I may downvote a question when I close it but that may not be just because it is an off topic question. A better "solution" to this is to just notify a voter that a question they voted on and voted to close has since been reopened so the users themselves can decide if they want to change their vote.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Not sure it is a better solution. It actually requires you to really come back and that's not sure. If that doesn't happen, the incentive to improve and re-open a question is still not high. On the other hand I like it too and I think I have upvoted it for sure. If only it was already implemented.

Comment: But that's the point, a user cast a vote for a reason, the system shouldn't change that just because, it should be asking the user if they want to change it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder As you said yourself: part of the downvoting will be because the question was off-topic. That reason is obsolete after re-opening. Your solution is only better if people actually do come back upon notification. If they don't then my solution might be better.

Comment: Right but the system shouldn't assume that is the reason for the downvote. It might even have been reopened incorrectly as you mentioned so _if_ it is the reason for the downvote it should remain and the question re-closed. etc. etc.

Comment: As somebody who clears the multiple review queues daily, I don't want dozens of notifications in my inbox, which indicates a answer/question has been improved.  I would be willing to look through a personal queue of questions and answers which have been edited that I issued any vote on.  If I started to get notification of every contribution that was changed after I issued a vote, I would delete my account, because I would be flooded with notifications.  There are days where the number of answers, which are actually new questions, are double digits.  I don't want dozens of notifications daily.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid potential answerers needing to volunteer too much more effort than what is required to answer a clear question, I think it is more important to reward those who ask clear questions.

For those whose questions require additional curation effort (sometimes considerable) to be volunteered in order to make them clear a single upvote already wipes out five downvotes so I do not think a higher level of forgiveness for the previous state(s) of their question is warranted.

If a question is ready to be re-opened I would usually expect it also to be ready to start attracting upvotes.

We need askers to learn how to ask clearly as quickly as possible.  That way we can focus on answering their questions in preference to making them clear before we can start to.

Comment: I also mentioned the additional curation effort in the question. I wonder if you are concerned in any way about people then not bothering to improve their questions anymore but just to keep asking new questions (until maybe they run out of this privilege)? After all asking a new question has the benefit of starting fresh.

Comment: When that happens the new copy of the question should be marked as a duplicate. A community will often respond to such duplicates with downvotes so it’s not a fresh start and often leads to early question limiting.

Comment: I did not mean duplicates (anyway you cannot have a closed question as duplicate target, can you?). I meant instead of going through the hassle of improving your question, voting to re-open and then somehow making the score even again and waiting for an answer, just ask a new question with the improved content. That should not be a duplicate and it would start with score 0 and could be answered right away. Sounds to me like the clear better deal. Those who don't learn at all will of course run into a question block at some point, but they anyway don't get their questions re-opened.

Comment: I think you may be surprised how often the new copy is spotted and made a duplicate of the old and if it’s also downvoted a user has two strikes to feed into the question limiting algorithm.

Comment: Moderators can make closed questions a duplicate target even when they have no answers and moderators are only ever a flag away.

Comment: "*a single upvote already wipes out five downvotes*": that is, if you only care about rep. And only the asker is affected by that. The question will still show "-4" to everyone, which may not reflect the improvements made, may be confusing to visitors, and may discourage answerers to have a look at it.

Comment: @dimlostfaithinSE the idea is not to let your questions get to anything like -5 by reading and re-reading them before posting, to make sure what they ask is clear.

Comment: @dimlostfaithinSE - The amount of votes to a question has never determine if the question is worth of being answered.  I would not advise to resubmit a question after the first attempt was closed.  The first question was likely closed for a reason.  The first attempt should simply be improved until the community reopens it.  Once reopened it does not matter what the score of the question is.  If I see a second and third attempt to ask the question, I am going to flag those attempts, in order for a moderator to handle the situation.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, when in the front page, I see a question with -4, or even -2/-3, it doesn't encourage me from trying to answer it. I known it will likely be poorly written and probably unanswerable. So, yes: it *does* determine, at least to me, wether the question is worth of being answered. I'm probably not the only one.

Comment: I have seen some gems that were initially downvoted only to be modified and improved significantly.  I guess the point of my comment is the score of the question should not determine if you should answer it.  If it's within scope of the community then effort to improve the question so it can be answered should be made.  Otherwise it will just be roomba