# Downvote for off topic after migration

Tags: feature-request, migration

I posted a question on Home Improvement, then it is migrated to Super User and get downvoted due to off topic there. It's my fault to be off topic on HI but not on SU. HI rep should change but not SU.

Can SE be changed to prevent such thing, like no off topic close on the new site, and it can only be kicked back to the original site (I guess rep change get reset during this process) and get down voted and closed there?

Comment: Now answered, the remaining feature request is the same as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can SE be changed to prevent such thing, like no off topic close on the new site, and it can only be kicked back to the original site (I guess rep change get reset during this process) and get down voted and closed there?

As far as I'm aware, something like this is already in place. If a question is migrated, only to be closed on the site it was migrated to, it'll be kicked back to the site it was first posted on, and the "This question was migrated..." message box will change to reflect that the migration failed. I think the question also gets closed automatically in this instance. I don't know whether any rep changes you accrued on the second site are reset, though.

I personally *hate* it when questions get migrated or redirected to sites where they're equally off-topic. It's a terrible experience for the asker, because their question's now been closed twice, and it's a terrible experience for the second site who has to, for lack of a better term, clean up the first site's mess. So I deeply sympathise with your plight.

Comment: Doesn't work for my question, it remains on Super User, bug?

Comment: It hadn't been closed on Super User when you posted that comment. [It has been now](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/186557). [The version on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1532637) does still remain, though, which is something I didn't realise would happen.

Comment: Then is that a bug? My rep change on SU is still there, according to this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration/31091#31091, migrated downvote will be cleared right? Doesn migration back have a different behavior?

Comment: Do not worry about the copy on SU. As a closed question with negative score and no answers, it will get automatically deleted after some time (which will also reverse your reputation loss).

Answer (score 4):

> Can SE be changed to prevent such thing, like no off topic close on the new site, and it can only be kicked back to the original site

It already *does* work like this: if a migrated question gets closed on the target site, this means the migration is rejected and the question returns to the original site (remaining in a closed state).

Comment: Doesn't work for my question

Comment: Your question on Super User is *not* closed.