# Feature request: Vote to clear the score (reset upvotes + downvotes to 0)

Tags: feature-request, privileges, score, se-quality-project

I would like to propose a new mechanism to help demote and occasionally remove stale content from the site.

There are two important cases where this is currently a problem:

- Poor questions by new users tend to accrue a heavy amount of downvotes. If they edit their question and it becomes acceptable, there should be a mechanism to clear out the now-obsolete feedback. This should also help improve the new user experience.
- Old answers which used to be correct are very hard to correct over time. When there are newer answers which should override the once correct advice, we would like to be able to level the playing field for them, as it were.

I'm intentionally vague on what exactly the implementation should look like, or what level of reputation this privilege should require. I'm thinking at least 10k.

Also, there would need to be a consensus on how many of these votes are required to actually clear the score, or what exactly should happen then. I'm thinking at least five votes should be required (perhaps with a separate process to bring back the old score, to enable us to reverse this decision when it was done hastily or because of a misunderstanding?) and there should be a banner of some sort to show that this has happened, maybe something like

> (blue background)
>
> This answer had its upvotes and downvotes reset to zero on 2023-04-01 by user00001, user00002, user00003, user00004, user00005
>
> At the time of the reset, there were 42 upvotes and 13 downvotes.

I suppose the voters should get their reputation recompensated when this happens, to also bring some limited visibility when you are not actively following the fate of a post you visited and voted on a long time ago.

---

I was somewhat surprised that I was unable to find an existing proposal for something similar. All I could find so far were posts about resetting the score and/or votes for migrated questions ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration)) and a [negatively-received and closed Stack Overflow meta about one of the cases above.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397888/reset-negative-vote-after-question-has-improved)

Comment: What would happen to the question asker's reputation?  
-42 x 10 + 13 x 1 = -407  
?

Comment: Good point. The current system lets you keep your reputation if it was accrued long ago when an old post is deleted, for example. Maybe that's a better model actually.

Comment: There is one case where I see this handy. If a user improves a question that was deleted by the Roomba as having a negative score and no answers after 30 days and pushes (on chat or the per-site meta) for the fixed question to be undeleted, they must then push for the score to be put back up to zero or higher to avoid it being re-deleted by the weekly script within a few days to possibly a few minutes later (depending on the time between undeletion and the next scheduled run). If the question in its past state had lots of downvotes, trying to get the score back to 0 within that timeframe...

Comment: ...would be very difficult, especially if the timing of the undeletion was right before the next script run. Also, if Community re-deletes a question that was undeleted by normal users, those same users can't vote to undelete again and the user will have to push all over again with new users (50% more users if they previously voted to undelete). It would be much better if users could not only undelete but also reset the votes so that it won't be immediately re-deleted.

Comment: All of that said, I see the drawbacks outweigh the benefits here. I believe a better way to fix that issue with the Roomba is simply to have it "reset the clock" if a question gets undeleted - that is, treat the time of undeletion as the time it was originally asked, so once it's undeleted it will have another 30 days before it's deleted again. This would be more than enough time for the score to correct itself or for someone to eventually find a solution and post an answer, preventing it from being auto-deleted.

Comment: @Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog It´s really hard, at least in my opinion imposible, to get a post undeleted, so this case don´t play a big role.

Answer (score -2):

- I believe the first scenario has to do with new users often being too eager to get answers and/or too lazy to read through the Help section of a website that is very obviously different from other sites; and established users acting too harshly to newcomers, but subsequently caring too little/having too little time to change their feedback based on changes to the downvoted posts.

  I think a better and less intrusive solution here would be for the latter to receive updates on edits on questions(/answers) a user has downvoted.
- I'm not sure your idea would work well for your second scenario, either: resetting a score doesn't necessarily mean users will go through them again, or that the more up-to-date ones get better scores. Old answers remain old answers, unless you bump them up to the main page again, which would just mean more noise (and less attention for new questions). Moreover, this action would need to be performed regularly.

  (Originally, I mentioned how the problems with the second scenario you sketch would be partially relieved by the roll-out of the '[version labels for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370640/version-labels-for-answers)', but it was brought to my attention this idea is off the table, for now.)

Comment: "I think a better and less intrusive solution here would be for the latter to receive updates on edits on questions(/answers) a user has downvoted." Agree, defenetly a better solution.

Answer (score -2):

I think the site system has already mechanisms to achieve the goals behind your questions, at least mostly.

When a question was written so bad it collected several downvotes, the OP can delete it, write a new question which now meets the expected quality standards and ask it as a new one, starting with a score of zero. Of course, the new question should really be a huge improvement, otherwise the new question will follow the road of the first one quickly, bringing the OP a step further to a temporary suspension.

Old answers which used to be correct, but got really incorrect over time are rare. Answers which got somewhat outdated are not so rare, but everyone can see when the question was asked and when the answer was given, that is something any reader of an answer should take into account. But when a "nowadays more elegant" or "nowadays more correct" answer to an older question is given, high-rep users can always boost the visibility of such an answer by awarding some bounty points to it.

Comment: The problem with deleted low-score questions is that they too count towards a question ban. I used to encourage newcomers to delete and try again but I'm hesitant to do that once I understood the possible repercussions.

Comment: @tripleee: yes, I know, and I don't think a question which needs to be "resetted" should count differently.